# How to change the default character set for the database connection?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I cannot enter(via php) Turkish characters correctly into PhpMyadmin. I set everything(browser encoding, html charset, database collation en connection) to UTF-8..

and my query

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  session_start();

  mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass');
  mysql_select_db('myDatabase');
  mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_turkish_ci'");
?>
```

P.S:As I change the text on database and write it correctly, I can display them normal on the browser

So the problem is entering text via php correctly into database..

I used msqli to find what the problem was:

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  session_start();
  $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass');
  mysql_select_db('myDatabase');
  mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_turkish_ci'");

  /* check connection */
      if (!$link) {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
      exit();
  }

 /* Print current character set */
      $charset = mysqli_character_set_name($link);
      printf ("Current character set is %s\n",$charset);

 /* close connection */
      mysqli_close($link);

 ?>
```

output(the default character set for the database connection) is "Current character set is latin1"

1- I can't find that default 'latin1' in php.ini or somewhere else..where does it come from?

2- How can I change that to utf8_turkish_ci?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`mysql` and `mysqli` libraries create separate mysql sessions, to verify your charset setting in the `mysql` session, you can do the following:

```
mysql_select_db('myDatabase');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_turkish_ci'");
$rs = mysql_query("show variables like 'char%'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
print_r($row);
```